# How to Fix This SQL Loop (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have designed a loop but it's not working as I'd like it to, and I'm assuming there are better ways to do this, but I'm quite confused.

Basically, there are two tables.
BlogSubscribers and Users

The BlogSubscribers simply holds the User ID's for subscribers (correlating to the Users) table, and I am trying to fetch the "Gender" value of each user that is a subscriber, but that information is stored in the Users table.

The loop only goes through once (which is why I tried to loop it with integers) - how can I make this work + more efficient?

It'd be great if you could explain any answers you post so I know how the code works in future.

**$ID is just a GET paramater through the url, i.e ?Blog=$ID**

```
$GetSubInfo = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM BlogSubscribers WHERE BlogID = '$ID'");


$GetSubInfoCount = mysqli_num_rows($GetSubInfo);
$LoopCount = 0;

while($LoopCount < $GetSubInfoCount){
$GetSubs = mysqli_fetch_object($GetSubInfo);
$GetFemaleSubs = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '$GetSubs->UserID' AND Gender = 'Female'"));
$GetMaleSubs = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '$GetSubs->UserID' AND Gender = 'Male'"));
$GetOtherSubs = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '$GetSubs->UserID' AND Gender = 'Other'"));
$GetUnknownSubs = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '$GetSubs->UserID' AND Gender = 'Unknown'"));
$LoopCount = $LoopCount + 1;
}
```

Comment: Look up SQL JOINs and prepared statements.

Comment: you have to use JOINs for achieving above functionality

Comment: Any examples? @JonStirling

Comment: Examples of JOINs and prepared statements? Just google them.

Comment: Didn't fix it. Here's the new query example

`$GetMaleSubs = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT Users.Gender, Users.ID FROM Users INNER JOIN BlogSubscribers ON BlogSubscribers.UserID=Users.ID WHERE BlogSubscribers.BlogID = '$ID' AND BlogSubScribers.UserID = '$GetSubs->UserID' AND Users.Gender = 'Male'"));` @JonStirling

Comment: we cant read code in comments.. it makes our eyes bleed.